# Button pressed in one activity sets price range in another activity

Tags: c#, android

- I am writing an android app and in my main activity I have a group of 5 buttons. Essentially, I would like to assign different prices for an enumeration depending on the button selected.
- In my third activity, I would like to utilize the prices set in the enumeration in global data to calculate the transactions. In the first activity, you select a button based on what store you want.
- This would indicate which pricing group to use for a set list of objects. Then in the third activity, you would select the items and the price would be associated with it.
- Then the final activity will sum up the total and give a summary. How can I assign the prices in an enumeration in global data based on the button selected.
- And how can I  assign prices to the third activity based on the button/store selected?

Answer (score 0):

Either you can pass the value from 1st activity to 2nd activity and then from 2nd activity to 3rd using `Intents`.
For passing data between activities read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application).

or

You can set the selected value in `SharedPreference` on selection from 1st screen and read that value in your third activity. (This method will persist the value) For SharedPreference demo follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example).

One another way is, you can create a `Singleton Class` to maintain the status of whatever variable you want. Set the value from 1st activity and get it from the same class in your 3rd activity. [For Singleton class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-design-pattern/)